# Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; 'Error Code: 158Incorrect parameters in the call to native function 'concat' ' at line 13

Tags: mysql

my code as below:

```
SELECT CONCAT("A purchase with the purchase ID of ", PURCHASE.PurchaseID,
 " is an online purchase of type ",ONLINEPURCHASE.OnlineType, " 
 and also a walkin purchase of location ", WALIINPURCHASE.ShopLocation ) 
 from (PURCHASE, ONLINEPURCHASE,WALIKINPURCHASE)
 where (PURCHASE.PurchaseID=ONLINEPURCHASE.PurchaseID 
 and PURCHASE.PurchaseID=WALKINPURCHASE.PurchaseID);
```

i was trying to do The script finds all cases that violate in a database the following consistency constraint.
“A purchase which is an online purchase should NOT be a walk-in purchase”
The script must list the outcomes of verification of the consistency constraint as a single column table with the following messages as the following rows.
A purchase with the purchase ID of  is an online purchase of type  and also a walkin purchase of location

my database create as below:

```
-- CREATE TABLE AUTHOR
CREATE TABLE AUTHOR (
    AuthorID        VARCHAR(12)     NOT NULL,
    Name            VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT AUTHOR_PKEY PRIMARY KEY (AuthorID)
);

-- CREATE TABLE BOOK
CREATE TABLE BOOK (
    BookID          VARCHAR(12)     NOT NULL,
    Title           VARCHAR(80)     NOT NULL,
    Price           DECIMAL(4,2)    NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT BOOK_PKEY PRIMARY KEY (BookID)
);

-- CREATE TABLE BOOKAUTHOR
CREATE TABLE BOOKAUTHOR (
    BookID          VARCHAR(12)     NOT NULL,
    AuthorID        VARCHAR(12)     NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT BOOKAUTHOR_PKEY PRIMARY KEY (BookID, AuthorID),
CONSTRAINT BOOKAUTHOR_FKEY1 FOREIGN KEY (BookID) REFERENCES BOOK (BookID),
CONSTRAINT BOOKAUTHOR_FKEY2 FOREIGN KEY (AuthorID) REFERENCES AUTHOR (AuthorID)
);

-- CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER (
    CustomerID      VARCHAR(12)     NOT NULL,
    Name            VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT CUSTOMER_PKEY PRIMARY KEY (CustomerID)
);

-- CREATE TABLE PURCHASE
CREATE TABLE PURCHASE (
    PurchaseID          VARCHAR(12)     NOT NULL,
    PurchaseQty         DECIMAL(4)      NOT NULL,
    PurchaseDate        DATE            NOT NULL,
    BookID          VARCHAR(12)     NOT NULL,
    CustomerID      VARCHAR(12)     NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PURCHASE_PKEY PRIMARY KEY (PurchaseID),
CONSTRAINT PURCHASE_FKEY1 FOREIGN KEY (BookID) REFERENCES BOOK (BookID),
CONSTRAINT PURCHASE_FKEY2 FOREIGN KEY (CustomerID) REFERENCES CUSTOMER (CustomerID)
);

-- CREATE TABLE ONLINEPURCHASE
CREATE TABLE ONLINEPURCHASE (
    PurchaseID      VARCHAR(12)     NOT NULL,
    OnlineType      VARCHAR(12)     NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT ONLINEPURCHASE_PKEY PRIMARY KEY (PurchaseID),
CONSTRAINT ONLINEPURCHASE_FKEY1 FOREIGN KEY (PurchaseID) REFERENCES PURCHASE (PurchaseID)
);

-- CREATE TABLE WALKINPURCHASE
CREATE TABLE WALKINPURCHASE (
    PurchaseID      VARCHAR(12)     NOT NULL,
    ShopLocation    VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT WALKINPURCHASE_PKEY PRIMARY KEY (PurchaseID),
CONSTRAINT WALKINPURCHASE_FKEY1 FOREIGN KEY (PurchaseID) REFERENCES PURCHASE (PurchaseID)
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table name is wrong. Inside the **CONCAT** function you call it `WALIINPURCHASE` and in the **FROM** you call it `WALIKINPURCHASE`. See below:

`from (..., ..., WALIKINPURCHASE)`

And:

`CONCAT(..., ..., ..., ..., ..., WALIINPURCHASE.ShopLocation)`

The correct one, according to your **CREATE** SQL is `WALKINPURCHASE`.

Correcting it to `WALKINPURCHASE` on **CONCAT** and **FROM** should solve your problem.

Comment: Did you change all the references for this table to `WALKINPURCHASE`?

Comment: yes  SELECT CONCAT("A purchase with the purchase ID of ", PURCHASE.PurchaseID,
 " is an online purchase of type ",ONLINEPURCHASE.OnlineType, " 
 and also a walkin purchase of location ", WALKINPURCHASE.ShopLocation ) 
 from (PURCHASE, ONLINEPURCHASE,WALKINPURCHASE)
 where (PURCHASE.PurchaseID=ONLINEPURCHASE.PurchaseID 
 and PURCHASE.PurchaseID=WALKINPURCHASE.PurchaseID);

Comment: I ran your CREATE SQL and then executed the SELECT. Everything worked fine, without errors. Can you please make sure that the table name is correct on your database and that there are no typos?